# Ape package - extracting distances between nodes

Tags: ape

I'm working with ape package currently. My idea is to extract tip labels corresponding to each node and also distances in between the nodes. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to interpret distances between nodes/tips in a `phylo` object (note that for `dispRity::tree.age` you'll need to install `dispRity` from GitHub https://github.com/TGuillerme/dispRity):

```
set.seed(1)
tree <- rtree(5)
tree$node.label <- paste0("n", 6:9)
plot(tree)
nodelabels(tree$node.labe)
axisPhylo()

## The distance between each tip
cophenetic(tree)

## The height of each tip and node
library(dispRity)
dispRity::tree.age(tree, order = "present")

## The distance between each nodes/tips
distances <- cbind(tree$edge, tree$edge.length)
colnames(distances) <- c("from", "to", "distance")
distances
```

This distance table reads as from element (tip/node) n to element (tip/node) m. The numbering works as follow: 1 is the first tip in the tree (`tree$tip.label[1]`), 2 is the second etc... 6 (number of tips + 1) is the first node in the tree (`tree$node.label[1]`), etc.